# FFmpeg -map 0 fails with error "Number of stream maps must match number of output streams"

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use Ubuntu's ffmpeg to convert a file to MKV while copying all the video and subtitle streams, but converting all the audio streams to AC3.

Using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -ab 256k output.mkv
```

fails with

```
Number of stream maps must match number of output streams
```

Removing the `-map 0` fixes the problem, but not all of the subtitle streams are in the output file.

**Edit**

Here's the full console output:

```
user@laptop:~/$ ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -ab 256k output.mkv
ffmpeg version 0.8.5-6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jan 24 2013 14:49:20 with gcc 4.7.2
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
[matroska,webm @ 0xa0cb20] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Duration: 00:10:56.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080, PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: dca (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0.2(eng): Subtitle: pgssub (default)
    Stream #0.3(fre): Subtitle: pgssub
    Stream #0.4(spa): Subtitle: pgssub
Number of stream maps must match number of output streams
```

Comment: Please post the full, uncut console output. I'm guessing this is because (from the docs), *"ffmpeg includes only one stream of each type (video, audio, subtitle) present in the input files and adds them to each output file."*

Comment: OK, I posted it.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you're seeing doesn't really make sense, but given that you're using the broken and "fake" `ffmpeg` that's actually from Libav and [not the real deal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756), it's probably a bug that has long been fixed. Just a matter of using a recent version where this works normally.

Download a recent static build [from the FFmpeg homepage](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or [compile it yourself](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

You can shorten down the command to:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c copy -c:a ac3 -map 0 out.mkv
```

FFmpeg will now automatically copy all the streams and map them all to the output, e.g. like this:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> ac3)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:4 (copy)
```